# Swift close API connection

Tags: swift, api, urlsession

If I am using this way to connect to an API, does this create a connection session? and how do I close it so next time it runs it will not take too much time because there is another session open?!

```
do {
    let data = try String(contentsOf: url)
    if !data.isEmpty {
        // use data
    }
} catch {
    print("Log \(error)")
}
```

**UPDATE**

My session will retrieve news from the API and draw markers on a map according to those news latitude and longitude. The API request always takes about a second, but after that drawing the markers take different time. When I navigate to another view then come back to the map view, the app send a new request to the API and raw the new response news markers. Every time I navigate back to map, it takes more time to draw the markers These are the time differences the app takes from start the API request until the markers are completely drawn:

1st time took: 7 seconds

2nd time took: 18 seconds

3rd time took: 30 seconds

4th time took: 38 seconds

5th time took: 49 seconds

I have tried `task.suspend()`, `task.cancel()`, and `session.invalidateAndCancel()` but it still same result.

How can I fix this timing problem?

```
func getData() {
    let urlString = URLFactory()
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        // Set up the URL request
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString.getWebserviceURL()) else {
            NSLog("Log Error: cannot create URL")
            self.processData()
            return
        }
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

        if self.task != nil {
            NSLog("Log suspend task")
            self.task!.suspend()
        }

        // make the request
        self.task = self.session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) in
            NSLog("Log start task")
            // check for any errors
            guard error == nil else {
                NSLog("Log error calling GET on webservice/getAllData: \(error!)")
                self.processData()
                return
            }
            // make sure we got data
            guard let responseData = data else {
                NSLog("Log Error: did not receive data")
                self.processData()
                return
            }
            // parse the result as JSON, since that's what the API provides
            do {
                guard let stringResponse = String(data: responseData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
                    self.processData()
                    return
                }
                let json = JSON(parseJSON: stringResponse)
                if (json["data"].arrayObject != nil) {
                    self.parse(json: json)
                }
                self.processData()
            }
        })

        self.task!.resume()
    }
}

private func processData() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if(!self.newsObj.isEmpty) {
            self.drawMarker { () -> () in
                self.stopActivityIndicator()
                NSLog("Log Finished loading markers")
            }
        } else {
            self.showToast(message: "No data found")
        }
    }
}

private func parse(json: JSON) {
    newsObj.removeAll()
    for data in json["data"].arrayValue {
        // parse news data to newsObject
        newsObj.append(news)
    }
}

private func drawMarker(completion: (() -> ())) {
    if mapView != nil {
        mapView.clear()
        startActivityIndicator("Loading Markers...")
        for news in newsObj {
            let marker = GMSMarker()
            let listLatLng = news.getLatlong()
            for latlng in listLatLng {
                // Do stuff ...
                }
            }
            marker.map = self.mapView
        }
        completion()
    } 
}
```

Comment: There is no session here. But you should not be using this code unless `url` is a local file URL. You really should be using `URLSession`.

Comment: @rmaddy url is a variable that contains the http url to the api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really not be using this method unless `url` is a local file only. You should be doing this in `URLSession`, here's how:

```
let task = URLSession().dataTask(with: URL.init(string: "")!, completionHandler: {data, response, error in
    if error != nil{
        print("Log \(error)")
        return //Stops the function
    }
    guard let data = data else{
        return
    }
    guard let stringResponse = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) else{
        return
    }
    print("Log \(stringResponse)")
})

task.resume()
```

In the above example, `stringResponse` holds the data as a String from the URL.

Also make sure you're using HTTPS, not HTTP

Comment: Thank you a lot! how can I cancel thee task after it's completed? where should I call task.cancel()?

Comment: `task.suspend()` will pause the task indefinitely

Comment: Please check my update!